# telegraph cucumber yellowish leaf and cracks

Tags: leaves, cucumbers

I have a variety of cucumbers planted and one telegraph cucumber plant seems to be having problems, leaves are more yellow and there are some cracks:
[image: telegraph cucumber plant]

the plant is next to other types of cucumbers, Armenian and Cucamelon, and there other telegraph cucumbers also which are doing fine, here's all of them:
[image: all the cucumbers]

does this plant have some disease, can it be helped ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have things worsened since you posted this?
The large leaf with the cracks just looks like heat stress to me.  I also see some yellow speckling on one leaf that could be from insects (harmless).
Have you or any of your neighbors sprayed for weeds..within wind blowing distance?

Comment: It didn't worsen, there are tomatoes nearby, and they have been sprayed with liquid copper, and they also had some sort of black micro flies , and they have been sprayed for that as well. Same spraying was used for white peach trees which had many micro insects under the leaves

Comment: Hello Omu!  
That is all good news.  Hoping that you'll be trellising the cucumbers.  I grew Cucamelons last year...made for much interesting conversation:)